# How do I access the location of a file in RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource on the client side

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-roles

I'm trying to present a file in a client side javascript viewer.  The file is originally stored in Azure storage.  I can't display the file in the viewer using the remote Azure URL due to CORS.  So I'm downloading it to RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource but I don't have a relative path that I can access the file.  It's still giving me a CORS error.

What's the best method for accessing the file on the client?

TIA

Comment: A little bit off-topic comment but according to Scott Guthrie, CORS support in Windows Azure storage is coming in next few weeks: https://twitter.com/scottgu/status/341780823390957568.

Comment: @GauravMantri very relevant.  TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access it directly from the client. A local resource is local (to the role).

I suggest you implement [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ezc17x8.aspx). This is a simple interface that allows you to return whatever you want (almost...) by implementing the [ProcessRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest.aspx) method.

Modified version of the code in the above link to ProcessRequest:

```
using System.Web;

namespace HandlerExample
{
   public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
   {
      public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
      {
        // Get the file from azure storage here and return it using context.Response
      }

      public bool IsReusable
      {
         get { return true; }
      }
   }
}
```

To register the handler, see [How to: Register HTTP Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx).

Note that there is also an async counterpart, [IHttpAsyncHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpasynchandler.aspx).